# How to find out if there is a line break in a JLabel when using HTML?

Tags: java, html, jlabel

I am using the HTML style formatting with JLabels - which I find very powerful.

```
JLabel jLabel;
jLabel.setText("<html><center>Long long text with many many words</center>`</html>");
```

As you can see, any text I enter into the JLabel - gets centered and can even go into "next line" (do a line break) if the horizontal space is shorter than the length of the text.

My question now is: is there a way to detect if such a line break occurred?

For example I want my code to act in a different way if some text is long enough for a line break and different if it fits to one line.

Something like: `.getNumberOfLineBreaks()`

Comment: have you tried setting the width inside the `JLabel` ?
i.e, `jLabel.setText("<html><body  style='width: 100px'> .....");`

Comment: also, have a look at [LineBreakMeasurer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/LineBreakMeasurer.html)

Comment: nope I didnt buwt how eould I know if there is a line break even then? I have no problem with the line breaks, they are ok, I just need to know if there is one or not :)